# How to check runtime json object type in android?

Tags: android

How can I create dynamic model based on the response of the JSON? I have a response where there are number of fields in which there are some fields are string and some of them are boolean. For Example

Suppose, a user have their own data like id, name, city, phone, address etc. Sometimes when user optional fields is phone or city or address then might he/she didn't enter while they register.

When I get the list of the user's the optional fields like city or phone is false(boolean) if user's not entered while they were signup or register. Similarly, when some user entered while they were registering. For example user no 1 have all the information id, name, city, phone and address while he/she registering. When I get the list of the user's particular object of the JSON will come's up with the value like "phone":"123567980", "email":"abc@gmail.com".

So what I will try to create is dynamic model based on the whatever the value's come in any of the datatype it's will handle while parsing those data in java?

See the difference between objects

```
{
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Administrator",
                "email": "admin@example.com",
                "phone": false,
                "street": false,
                "city": false,
                "state_id": false,
                "country_id": false
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Quadrastores",
                "email": "info@quadrastores.com",
                "phone": "+965 99964854",
                "street": "Shop 29, Qairawan complex, Ibn khaldoun St. Hawalli",
                "city": "Kuwait",
                "state_id": false,
                "country_id": [
                    122,
                    "Kuwait"
                ]
            },
```

Am I on the correct way please suggestion or example of it if it's possible to do so.

Comment: You can try with `instanceof`

Comment: I have tried with it but there are some relational object as well. Like JSONArray when value is there it's come up with the value and when there is no value of that it's comes up with the false(Boolean).

Comment: I have entered the json response into it.

Comment: Why can't it be null instead of false?

Comment: you can try with `has()` or `containskey()`

Comment: It's python based API response it's not a completely REST API. It's not handle from the python end to check the each and every fields.

Comment: for null issue use `isNull()`

Comment: are you using Retrofit for that?

Comment: Guys, How can i implement just try to create a model with the second user  data and try to fullfill the requirement when data is available and when data not available.

Comment: No I haven't use Retrofit.

Comment: When the user leaves any field blank, just add its argument when posting the data to either as `null` or as an empty String (""). Other thing is that you can make some fields as `required`. Also I do not recommend using Boolean as a type for fields like phone, street, city, state_id, etc, as they are more of String types.

Comment: @MilanGajera check out my answer, you have an idea there on how to create more typesafe object from the one incoming from the API

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion what you can do is you can use 'Object' or 'Any' as the type, and then use `is` or `instanceof` to check the type and create the model properly. But it will be neverending story with type casting and checking:

```json
 {
    "id": Int,
    "name": String,
    "email": String,
    "phone": Object,
    "street": Object,
    "city": Object,
    "state_id": Object,
    "country_id": Object
}
```

What you can do is to create your second model with proper tpes, and just transform the one incoming from API to it:

```json
API model:
 {
    "id": Int,
    "name": String,
    "email": String,
    "phone": Object,
    "street": Object,
    "city": Object,
    "state_id": Object,
    "country_id": Object
}

Your Model:
 {
    "id": Int,
    "name": String,
    "email": String,
    "phone": String?, // nullable,
    "street": String?, // nullable,
    "city": String?, // nullable,
    "state_id": Int?, // nullable,
    "country_id": List<Any>?, // nullable
}
```

And in the code:

```java
String jsonString = yourJsonAsString;
YourModel model = new YourModel();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

Object phone = json.get("phone");
if(phone instanceof String){
    model.setPhone(phone.toString());
} else {
    model.setPhone(null);
}
```

And so on